# C++ Image Processing Libraries

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am looking for a C++ library for image processing. I need the library to threshold a PPM photo (color photo). Should I write my own code? what do you guys think?

Answer (score 15):

[Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/?ImageMagick=euqj79qcd73925ive9hf8sme42) might help. It's the library version of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 13):

All of the above options should be able to do what you required.

I would like to add [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to the list. It's a fast cross-platform computer vision library with extensive image loading, saving and processing support. It's written in C, but it has a solid C++ interface, which I have used in the past.

That being said: [Reading / writing PPMs is straight-forward](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html), so if all you need is to read and threshold, you should definitely consider doing it yourself. It would come down to reading the PPM bytes into memory, greyscaling by averaging the RGB color channels (note that averaging the RGB channels is one, very simple, method to greyscale; there are [more](http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/)), then thresholding and writing away.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) library. It's extremely powerful and versatile and may actually suit all your needs *(well, yep, it's boost :)*.

Comment: Please update the link to [Boost GIL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/gil/doc/html/index.html). So it points always to the current version.

Answer (score 9):

The [Simd Library](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) The  is a free open source image processing library, designed for C and C++ programmers. It provides many useful high performance algorithms for image processing such as: pixel format conversion, image scaling and filtration, extraction of statistic information from images, motion detection, object detection (HAAR and LBP classifier cascades) and classification, neural network.

The algorithms are optimized with using of different SIMD CPU extensions. In particular the library supports following CPU extensions: SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2 and AVX-512 for x86/x64, VMX(Altivec) and VSX(Power7) for PowerPC, NEON for ARM.

The Simd Library has C API and also contains useful C++ classes and functions to facilitate access to C API. The library supports dynamic and static linking, 32-bit and 64-bit Windows and Linux, MSVS, G++ and Clang compilers, MSVS project and CMake build systems.

P.S. I participate in the development of this project.

Comment: It seems like a cool library! Are you also the author? If so, you should probably mention it in the answer (see [affiliation disclosure](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior))

Comment: I didn't know this rule.

Comment: Does Simd library has any feature that would combine two images vertically such that (500x500, 500x500) becomes (500x1000)? I haven't learned C++ yet and I am trying to find a library that can do this (to be used in android). Can you help

Comment: @rupinderjeet Of course, Simd Library allows to do this: Simd::Copy(a, c.Region(0, 0, 500, 500).Ref()); Simd::Copy(b, c.Region(0, 500, 1000, 500).Ref());

Answer (score 6):

[The CImg Library](http://cimg.eu) is a popular choice too. It is really simple to use, lightweight and already have a lot of basic and advanced image processing operators implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Very good library is [GD2](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/)

This library has multiple languages bindings, including C (which is compatible with C++ of course). It is easy to build GD as a static or dynamic library with actually any C++ compiler, including GCC and Visual C++, also pre-built binaries are available over Internet.
Unlike Boost image library, it allows to load/save images from/to memory and not hard drive only.

Comment: I believe boost GIL also allows writing/reading to/from memory.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add [VIPS](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS) to the list. The library is particularly suitable for machines with many CPUs. For a comparison, see the benchmarks [here](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Speed_and_Memory_Use).