# Trying to compile DevIL on x64 FreeBSD

Tags: c++, freebsd, devil, .a

tarball: DevIL-1.7.8.tar.gz

I've installed DevIL 1.7.8 on FreeBSD 10.3 x64 when I try to link it, I get these errors:

> ......
> lib/libIL.a(libIL_la-il_jp2.o): In function ilLoadJp2F':
> (.text+0x352): undefined reference to `jas_init'
>
> lib/libIL.a(libIL_la-il_png.o): In
> function iSavePngInternal': (.text+0xadd): undefined reference to`png_set_write_fn' ..........

Linking style in the Makefile:

```
-Idevil
-Ldevil/lib
-lIL -lpng -ltiff -lmng -llcms -ljpeg
```

When I try to use DevIL on my x86 bin everything works fine and it's succesfully linking. But no chance for amd_64..

Is it a bug? If it's a bug is there any alternatives that I can use instead of DevIL.. ?

Comment: Can you use ImageMagick? Also see this questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982711/c-image-processing-libraries On the other hand DevIL is already in ports, why do you need to compile it when you can simply install with `pkg`? https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=devil&stype=all&sektion=graphics

Comment: Because it gives same error even If I compile it with pkg...

Comment: `pkg` is not used to compile stuff, only to install. If you can't compile with, say, `ports-mgmt/synth` you may try to raise a bug in https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `-I/usr/local/include` and `-L/usr/local/lib` to your compilation and linking flags respectively.

But save yourself a lot of hassle and install it from ports or as a package.

To install the package, run `pkg install graphics/devil` as root.
This is easiest and fastest. But it doesn't have support for high dynamic range images enabled, nor SIMD autodetection (like AltiVec, SSE3,...).

If you need one of those, you have to build it from ports.
To install the port, make sure you have the ports tree installed, go to `/usr/ports/graphics/devil` and run `make install clean` as root.